# Suppose $\inf(A)=\frac{1}{A}$ then $\frac{1}{A}$ its bounded.

Tags: real-analysis

Good night. I have a problem with this:

> Suppose $\inf(A)=\frac{1}{A}$, then $\frac{1}{A}$ its bounded.

I make this:

Suppose the sequence $\left\{ A_{n}\right\} =\left\{ \frac{1}{a} \, : \,a\, \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, since $A$ is bounded the sequence $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} \rightarrow0$, $\frac{1}{A}$ is bounded.

I was thinking about that.  But i think it's too bad, someone help me?

Comment: What is $\frac 1A$ is $A$ is a set of numbers?

Comment: A is a set!! of R

Comment: I thought so, but that was not really my question. My question was, what is $\frac 1A$? Because as far as I can recall, I have never seen that operation before.

Comment: 1/A isn't defined to be any thing so $\inf A = 1/A$ is ... gobbledegook.

Comment: Since $A \subset \mathbb R$, I'm guessing that $1/A := \{1/x \mid x\in A\}$. Can you clarify if this is the intended meaning?

Comment: @Eff If so, then $\inf A = 1/A$ = another set is... still gobbledegook.

Comment: @fleablood You're right. Then that doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to define at least to things.  1) If A is a set you have to define 1/A.  2) Whatever you define 1/A as you have to define what for any $x \in A$ what does $x < 1/A$ mean?  It is not in the least bit clear what you think the answer to either of those are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{x| x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $\frac{1}{A}=\{p=\frac{1}{x}| x \in \mathbb{R}\}$
Now let **$\alpha =inf A $** $\implies \alpha \leq x  \forall x \in A$.
Since $\alpha $ is inf **no other lower bound exists**(i.e,$\nexists \beta $) s.t

$\alpha\leq \beta \leq x \forall x \in A$.

now look at the other set $\frac{1}{A}=\{p=\frac{1}{x}| x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

$ \alpha \leq x   \forall x \in A$

$\frac{1}{\alpha}\geq \frac{1}{x}\forall x \in A$

Let $\frac{1}{\alpha}=\gamma (say)$

$\implies\gamma \geq \frac{1}{x}\forall x \in A$

$\implies\gamma $ is upper bound for set $\frac{1}{A}$.

suppose there exists another upper bound say $\gamma '$
s.t $$\frac{1}{x}\leq\gamma ' \leq \gamma \forall x \in A $$

$$\implies x\geq \frac{1}{\gamma '}  \forall x \in A $$

$$\implies \exists \text{another lower bound for set A}$$
contadicts the fact that $\alpha$ is g.l.b

$\implies $ our assumption is wrong 
$\implies \nexists$ another upper bound $\gamma '$ for set $\frac{1}{A}$ 
$\implies \gamma \text{is least upper bound} \implies sup\frac{1}{A}=\alpha$

$\implies inf(A)=\frac{1}{sup(A)} $

Comment: Hih?  A = R and inf A = doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

As you say A is subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

**Inf A** is g.l.b of set A ,while $\frac{1}{A}=\{z=\frac{1}{x}|x \in A \}$.

I think Your question give some relation between **inf A** and **sup$\frac{1}{A}$**.

$\left\{ A_{n}\right\} =\left\{ \frac{1}{a} \, : \,a\, \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$,

since $A$ is bounded the sequence $\left\{ x_{n}\right\} \rightarrow0$,

$\frac{1}{A}=\{b= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}}| \frac{1}{a}\in A \}=\{b=a| \frac{1}{a}\in A \}$ .

$\implies$ set A has **l.u.b A=** 1 while set $\frac{1}{A}$ is bounded below and not bound above.